# Deploying RDL's through Visual Studio to an SSRS instance on Azure

Tags: visual-studio, azure, reporting-services, report, ssrs-2012

I am running into an issue with my deployment of SSRS RDL report files to my report server instance which is running on Azure.

The error I get when I deploy my reports is:

[image: error]

I have confirmed that I am able to access the report service URL from my web browser(it brings up the FTP-style directory listing of reports) but still receive this error.

This leads me to believe that I am unable to deploy to this server because of a permissions issue however I am unsure if I am able work around this as I tried going on the report server and creating permissions for my username but since the SSRS instance is not on my work server's domain(its hosted on azure) how would I go about creating permissions for my windows workstation user account(using my corporate domain) on the Azure SSRS instance?

This is quite frustrating as everytime I wish to deploy report changes I must manually copy the RDLs to the report server and upload them using the SSRS web interface one by one.

Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation you'll have to do the steps listed below. This is called the classic deployment model, but they recommend using the [Resource Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-deployment-model) instead:

Quoted from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-windows-classic-ps-sql-bi?toc=%2Fazure%2Fvirtual-machines%2Fwindows%2Fclassic%2Ftoc.json#reporting-services-native-mode-configuration):

- SQL Server Data Tools: Remote: On your local computer, create a Reporting Services project in SQL Server Data Tools that contains Reporting Services reports. Configure the project to connect to the web service URL.

[image]

- Create a .VHD hard drive that contains reports and then upload and attach the drive.

  - Create a .VHD hard drive on your local computer that contains your reports.
  - Create and install a management certificate.
  - Upload the VHD file to Azure using the Add-AzureVHD cmdlet Create and upload a Windows Server VHD to Azure.
  - Attach the disk to the virtual machine.